# designing a scrollview in stroyboard with xcode4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have created a app project with story board in Xcode4.5

I've created a table view, and embed with Navigation controller. After tap the table view cell, I've create a segue to a detailed view.

I need to put lots of information in this detailed view, so I decided to make a scroll view.

I've create a view controller and add a scroll view in the view, set the scroll view height larger than the view height, and I arrange the labels and image views in the scroll view.

*BUT* after I build and run the app, my scroll view can not scroll at all.
I'm not sure where was the problem. Can any one kindly pointed out?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**
my ItemViewController.h

```
#import 

@interface COSViewController : UIViewController
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *itemDetailScrollView;
@end
```

connect the itemDetailScrollView with Scrollview in connect inspector.

my ItemViewController.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.itemDetailScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);

}
```

Comment: Did you set the `contentSize`?

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling of scroll view depends on the content size.
Your content size needs to be greater than the size of the scrollview frame.

```
scrollView.contentSize = <Your actual content size>
```